# Template syntax error with RequestContext(request))

Tags: django

The following block of code is throwing an error and I can't figure out why -- I haven't changed it at all - this error just suddenly started happening:

```
def product_feed(request):
    """ Return all site activity from friends, etc. """
    if request.user.is_authenticated():
        return HttpResponseRedirect("/about/what_next/")
    else:
        return render_to_response("homepage.html", {}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

It's the last line where it returns render_to_response is where the problem occurs.

Error is:

```
Exception Type: SyntaxError at /
Exception Value: invalid syntax (views.py, line 804)
```

Screenshot also shows the issue.[image]

TRACEBACK:

```
Traceback:
File "/Users/NB/Desktop/myenv2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  111.                         response = callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "/Users/NB/Desktop/store/views.py" in product_feed
  261.      return render_to_response("homepage.html", {}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
File "/Users/NB/Desktop/myenv2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/shortcuts/__init__.py" in render_to_response
  20.     return HttpResponse(loader.render_to_string(*args, **kwargs), **httpresponse_kwargs)
File "/Users/NB/Desktop/myenv2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/loader.py" in render_to_string
  176.         return t.render(context_instance)
File "/Users/NB/Desktop/myenv2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
  140.             return self._render(context)
File "/Users/NB/Desktop/myenv2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/test/utils.py" in instrumented_test_render
  62.     return self.nodelist.render(context)
File "/Users/NB/Desktop/myenv2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
  823.                 bit = self.render_node(node, context)
File "/Users/NB/Desktop/myenv2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/debug.py" in render_node
  74.             return node.render(context)
File "/Users/NB/Desktop/myenv2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py" in render
  123.         return compiled_parent._render(context)
File "/Users/NB/Desktop/myenv2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/test/utils.py" in instrumented_test_render
  62.     return self.nodelist.render(context)
File "/Users/NB/Desktop/myenv2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
  823.                 bit = self.render_node(node, context)
File "/Users/NB/Desktop/myenv2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/debug.py" in render_node
  74.             return node.render(context)
File "/Users/NB/Desktop/myenv2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py" in render
  123.         return compiled_parent._render(context)
File "/Users/NB/Desktop/myenv2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/test/utils.py" in instrumented_test_render
  62.     return self.nodelist.render(context)
File "/Users/NB/Desktop/myenv2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
  823.                 bit = self.render_node(node, context)
File "/Users/NB/Desktop/myenv2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/debug.py" in render_node
  74.             return node.render(context)
File "/Users/NB/Desktop/myenv2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/defaulttags.py" in render
  281.                 return nodelist.render(context)
File "/Users/NB/Desktop/myenv2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
  823.                 bit = self.render_node(node, context)
File "/Users/NB/Desktop/myenv2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/debug.py" in render_node
  74.             return node.render(context)
File "/Users/NB/Desktop/myenv2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/defaulttags.py" in render
  411.             url = reverse(view_name, args=args, kwargs=kwargs, current_app=context.current_app)
File "/Users/NB/Desktop/myenv2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py" in reverse
  476.     return iri_to_uri(resolver._reverse_with_prefix(view, prefix, *args, **kwargs))
File "/Users/NB/Desktop/myenv2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py" in _reverse_with_prefix
  363.         possibilities = self.reverse_dict.getlist(lookup_view)
File "/Users/NB/Desktop/myenv2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py" in reverse_dict
  276.             self._populate()
File "/Users/NB/Desktop/myenv2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py" in _populate
  253.                     for name in pattern.reverse_dict:
File "/Users/NB/Desktop/myenv2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py" in reverse_dict
  276.             self._populate()
File "/Users/NB/Desktop/myenv2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py" in _populate
  265.                 lookups.appendlist(pattern.callback, (bits, p_pattern, pattern.default_args))
File "/Users/NB/Desktop/myenv2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py" in callback
  216.         self._callback = get_callable(self._callback_str)
File "/Users/NB/Desktop/myenv2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py" in wrapper
  27.         result = func(*args)
File "/Users/NB/Desktop/myenv2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py" in get_callable
  92.                 lookup_view = getattr(import_module(mod_name), func_name)
File "/Users/NB/Desktop/myenv2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/importlib.py" in import_module
  35.     __import__(name)

Exception Type: SyntaxError at /
Exception Value: invalid syntax (views.py, line 804)
```

Comment: Which version of Django are you using?  As of Django 1.5 the `url` tempaltetag will try to evaluate the url name so if "home" a variable then you're ok otherwise you'll need to wrap it in quotes

Comment: is line 804 the render_to_response line ?

Comment: I'm using Django 1.4 -- The weird thing is I haven't changed anything-- this was working this morning.

Comment: @karthikr no it is not. I have posted the full traceback.

Comment: what is line 804 of views.py  ? It says there is a syntax error there

Comment: OMG I feel so stupid. Is was an error in the views.py of a totally random app I was looking at and the traceback didn't even mention that. Why did the error reporting fail to mention the app name???? This is so misleading.

Comment: It is probably because you are not referencing that directly, python interpreter might have tried to interpret that and failed when it accessed the file. It does give the right error though